# Is there any way to set ansi_nulls on for multiple stored procedures at once with writing a script and not making changes to any system table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 100 of stored procedures with ansi_nulls off, and I am trying to set it ON. One way I can go to each stored procedure and set property>options>ansi_nulls ON, also can modify each of them with ansi_nulls ON and compile it. But it is very much time consuming to do for hundreds of SPs.

I would like to have a way where I can write a script to modify them with ansi_nulls on and execute it in same script without touching any system table. 
Well, I can use sys tables to just query the SPs to list them which I need to modify.

I appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Fortunately you can't do this in bulk. The reality is that you need to evaluate each procedure to make sure the logic is going to be ok when you turn ANSI_NULLS ON. Not sure how you were planning on changing this, you can't change that property in the Object Explorer. Also not sure how you plan on using sys.tables to tell you which procedures you need to change.

Comment: Agree with Sean. You really need to inspect each stored procedure and see whether its logic depended on ANSI_NULLs being off. That's not really something you can automate and even for human beings is tricky to determine - all you know is that some behaviour around nulls may change but it may not be documented how nulls *should* be handled in all cases.

Comment: Why do you not want to make use of the system tables to achieve this as well?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do and it certainly isn't time consuming:

1. In SQL Server Management Studio, right click the database in Object Explorer, go to Tasks, and Generate Scripts
2. Select "Select specific database objects" and check "Stored Procedures" and click Next
3. The default should be good (single file) on the Set Scripting Options screen except you need to pick your file output. Click Next and then Next again. It'll take a minute or five to generate the file.
4. Open the text/SQL file generated in a decent editor like Notepad++.
5. Mass replace `CREATE PROCEDURE` with `ALTER PROCEDURE`
6. If `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` was created in the script, replace `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` with `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`.
7. If `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` was not created, replace `ALTER PROCEDURE` with `SET ANSI_NULLS ON\r\nGO\r\nALTER PROCEDURE` where \r\n is of course a Carriage Return Line Feed combo. If your text editor can't create CrLFs, get a better text editor.

The text file should now be good to execute to correct the issue. **Test this before running the whole thing. Also, be sure to keep a backup of the original script.**

Comment: This will work great syntactically but it can very easily generate some serious logical issues in your code because NULL is suddenly treated differently. I would strongly advise you against just doing this without understanding the nuances of every procedure.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepsean I have tried the way you have suggested and it is working perfect for me. thank you for solutions.